# Coldfusion : Odd Output of Timestamp : Replaces with an x

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I think my timestamp needs to be at the end of the string.  But when I move it there - I get an odd output of the &times turns into an x.  Is there a fix for this?  At the front it works fine.

```
<cfset usem = "timestamp=#unixdatetimeNow.getTime()#&symbol=#pair#&side=#side#&type=#type#&quantity=#size#">
```

Outputs :

> timestamp=1645552579468&symbol=SHIBUSDT&side=sell&type=market&quantity=9005

```
<cfset usem = "symbol=#pair#&side=#side#&type=#type#&quantity=#size#&timestamp=#unixdatetimeNow.getTime()#">
```

Outputs with the x :

> symbol=SHIBUSDT&side=sell&type=market&quantity=9005×tamp=1645552579468

How do I fix this x replacement?  Does it in both cfset and in script

Comment: Weird. Seems like a bug with the parameter name `timestamp`, or it may just be a reserved word. Change the name to anything else, like "**&R**timestamp" and it works fine.

Comment: Oh wait, **&time**stamp is being treated as the html entity `&times`, that's why it's displaying  "x".

Comment: Try wrapping `#unixdatetimeNow.getTime()#` into `#EncodeForURL(unixdatetimeNow.getTime())#`

Comment: No luck James.  Why is it fine at the front but not back? Hmmmm.

Comment: Try this `<cfset usem = "symbol=#pair#&side=#side#&type=#type#&quantity=#size#&" & "timestamp=#unixdatetimeNow.getTime()#">`

Comment: @Merle_the_Pearl - When it is the first parameter, there is no `&` in front. `times` alone is  not considered an html entity, but `&times` is.

Comment: @user12031119 : No Go : symbol=SHIBUSDT&side=sell&type=market&quantity=9005×tamp=1645573615219

Comment: Fixed with : &amp; : <cfset usem = "symbol=#pair#&side=#side#&type=#type#&quantity=#size#&amp;timestamp=#unixdatetimeNow.getTime()#">

Comment: The actual string still contains `&time` - not `x`. Is it really causing a problem elsewhere, or just confusing when displayed on screen for debugging? https://trycf.com/gist/1ad70da80237605e9e72e881ecab714a/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: For example, it might display correctly on screen, but if used as a url query string, the url parameter name would become `&amp;timestamp` rather than `timestamp`.  So could you clarify what type of issues it's causing (other than displaying incorrectly on screen)?

Answer (score 1):

**Update: 2022-04-06**

***TLDR*;** Bottom line, nothing needs to be done.  As mentioned in the comments, and your other thread [ColdFusion : Binance API : Not all sent parameters were read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71240017/coldfusion-binance-api-not-all-sent-parameters-were-read), the parameter name is still `&timestamp`, it just *appears to be* `xtamp` when displayed on screen.

---

It's because the substring **&times** is being treated as the [html entity](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) `&times`, which gets rendered as the symbol `x`.

> Why is [timestamp] fine at the front but not back?

When `timestamp` is the first parameter in the query string, there's no `&` preceding "**time**". So it's not treated as an html entity.

Keep in mind this is just a presentation issue. The substring **&time** is only rendered as `x` when you *output* the variable. The actual contents of the variable don't change. So nothing happens its used in your cfhttp call:

```
 // sends "&timestamp" not "xstamp"
 cfhttp(....) {
    ...
    cfhttpparam(type="body", value="#yourString#");
 }
```

> Fixed with : `&amp;` : `<cfset usem = "...&amp;timestamp=#unixdatetimeNow.getTime()#">`

That might display correctly on screen, but will break your cfhttp call because it sets the parameter name to the literal string `&amp;timestamp` but the API is expecting a parameter named `timestamp`.